# Generics for Typesafe-Actions library

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

So I am using this library https://github.com/piotrwitek/typesafe-actions.
It has a method createAction with the following API.

```
createAction('action type', (resolve) => (payload: payloadType) => resolve(payload));
```

Now if i do

```
 createAction('action type',(resolve) => <T extends someType>(payload: payloadType<T>) => resolve(payload));
```

It simply fails. It infers type as `payloadType<someType>` instead of `payloadType<T extends someType>`.
Am I the only one having this issue. As a workaround i did implement a getter function but seems like a hack.
Any help on the same would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show what exactly have you done (hack)?

Comment: Well you could just create a seperate getter function which takes in action arguments and return the same and whenever you need to dispatch an action instead of providing the action arguments directly call the getter function to get strong typing.